# How to a Durandal widget return values?

Tags: widget, durandal, hottowel

I have a Durandal widget in Hot Towel Template and I need to use some values from widget in external view. I tried this:

```
<div data-bind="widget: { kind: 'myWidget', items: projects, value: newValue }"></div>
<span data-bind="text: newValue"></span>
```

But `newValue` is empty. In `controller.js` I set `settings.value` successfully, but I think that `settings` is only used to work along to the widget, but I need to get some values from Durandal widget. Is it possible?

I am new in Durandal widget, please any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem time ago. I solved this problem using the durandal events. You can find more information in the next url: http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Events/

Also in some cases I have use the url to send some information between a widget and a view, but it is for a very specific situation. When doing something in the widget implies to change the current view.

If you need more information about one of this solution, I can add some examples.

-----EDIT----

To throw an event in durandal you have to use the app module:

```
app.trigger("someEvent");
```

To catch this event, you have to do that:

```
app.on("someEvent", function () {
  //Do that you want
});
```

So, you can throw an event from the widget, and capture where you want.

Comment: I agree with you @new2cpp. But it was the only solution that I was able to find for it. It would be great if anyone can find another solution.